# Customizing max-width value for Bootstrap .container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am new to Bootstrap and maybe "asking the wrong question" but here it goes:

it seems that by default Bootstrap limits max-width for .container to 1170px:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1170px;
  }
}
```

In my ASP.Net MVC web application there is a table where 1170px is just not enough and application is targeted for desktops with 1920x1080 monitors. So I would like to utilize more of available space.

In ASP.Net MVC web application there is Site.css that is included after Bootstrap.css so I added this to Site.css:

```
@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1370px;
  }
}
```

<del>However, it has no effect. Now, if I change above snippet in Site.css to use 1200px instead 1500px it works but it wouldn't be correct to use this on browser window that is actually 1200px wide.</del>

<del>How can this be properly achieved: if browser window is at least 1500px wide then max-width for Bootstrap container would be set to 1370px? Or am I looking at this from the wrong angle?</del>

Actually, the snippet above works fine when added to Site.css. What was throwing me off was that I had Windows screen fonts set to 125% and it affects calculations - 1500px becomes 1500px*1.25=1875px and 1370px becomes 1712.5px. So as soon as my browser window width got less than 1875px (just a tad below full-screen) I would get dropped to the lower width range.

Comment: Any change if you use percentages `max-width: 90%;`?

Comment: why not you use .container-fluid so it expands to fill the available width.

Answer (score 3):

From what I can tell using Bootstrap v3.3.7 there is no max-width property on the container class.

There is a width property. Which will decide the actual width if it is smaller then max-width.

So you need to override the width property instead.

```
@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  .container {
    width: 1370px;
  }
}
```

or override the width with whatever % you choose plus a new max-width property.

Remember to load your own styles after bootstrap or you have to use !important.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is customizable, you can change your container size (and lots of other things) [here](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#grid-system). You may also want to add the `!important` attribute to your media query in site.css to get it to work:

```
@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  .container {
    width: 1370px !important;
  }
}
```

Also, make sure you change the media query in both CSS files, if you haven't tried that already.